# Using choices used in Models.py to route the page in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

I started a project in Django where I am making a new restaurant site. What I thought initially is to make a Model like this:

```
class Menu(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User,default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   name = models.CharField("Name of the dish",max_length=30)
   category = models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES,default='SP')
   description = models.TextField(max_length=300)
   dish_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/')
```

And I have CATEGORY_CHOICES as CATEGORY_CHOICES = [('L','Lunch'),.....]

Now I have this button on the index page that routes to menu page. **In Menu page**, I am thinking of **displaying the [n] number of tiles with the [name]** ( n = number of elements in category choices and name = the full name of it ex:Lunch)

After getting lots of error and figuring out each and every error, I have achieved this task. **Now**, after that, I want to **open the menu of particular category when user clicks in it**. Eg: If user clicks 'Lunch' tile, it should route to other page where all the list of the foods with that category are listed. My url pattern is like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('', views.index, name="index"),
  path('menu/', views.menu, name="menu"),
  path('menu/<str:menu_category>/', views.menu_detail, name="menu_detail"),
]
```

And I have this view :

```
def menu_detail(request, menu_category):
  menu_list = get_list_or_404(Menu ,category=menu_category)
  menu_title = Menu.objects.get(category=menu_category)
  return render(request,'restaurant/menu_detail.html',{'menu_list':menu_list,'menu_title':menu_title})
```

In the Menu template, I am calling it as

```
<a href="{% url 'menu_detail' menu_category = menus.menu_category %}">
```

I don't know where I have done wrong. But I am getting **ReverseMatchException** while browsing ..../menu/ . Maybe it's too complicated for me as I am new to this field. Can anybody please help?